# Recover EditText's value from a fragment to another

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My EditText is in my fragment named : **EquationsCalculFragment.java**
I want to recover the value in my fragment named : **EquationsResultat.java**

I have two `NullPointerException` with no apparent reasons (see the comments directly in the code).
NB : For the error in the EquationsResultsFragment, I tried to cast with `String.valueOf()`, with `Float.parseFloat()`, with the two combined... but no one worked.

**EquationsCalculFragment.java**

```
    public class EquationsCalculFragment extends Fragment {
        private ViewPager viewPager;
        private EditText champ_a;
        private EditText champ_b;
        private String a;
        private String b;

        public float getA_equa_2nd() {
            return Float.parseFloat(a);
        }

        public float getB_equa_2nd() {
            return Float.parseFloat(b);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_equations_calcul, container, false);

            viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

            champ_a = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.equa_2nd_a);
            champ_b = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.equa_2nd_b);

            Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_equations_resultats);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    b = champ_b.getText().toString();
                    a = champ_a.getText().toString();
                    EquationsResultatFragment eqResFr = new EquationsResultatFragment();
                    eqResFr.getResultat(getA_equa_2nd(), getB_equa_2nd()); //NullPointerException happens here
//at com.example.slabre.applitest.EquationsCalculFragment$1.onClick(EquationsCalculFragment.java:60)
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
                }
            });
            return view;
        }
    }
```

**EquationsResultat.java**

```
    public class EquationsResultatFragment extends Fragment {
        private TextView results;
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_equations_resultat, container, false);

            results = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.equa_2nd_resultat);

            return view;
        }

        public void getResultat(float a, float b) {
            results.setText(String.valueOf((a*a)+(2*a*b)+(b*b))); // NullPointerException happens here
// at com.example.slabre.applitest.EquationsResultatFragment.getResultat(EquationsResultatFragment.java:29)
       }
    }
```

Hope you can help me, I think this is not a big problem.

Parent Activity : **TabFragment.java** (yes my app si working with a TabLayout and ViewPager)

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_items = 3 ;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /**
         *Inflate tab_layout and setup Views.
         */
        View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,null);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        /**
         *Set an Apater for the View Pager
         */
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });

        return x;

    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        /**
         * Return fragment with respect to Position .
         */

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position){
                case 0 : return new EquationsCalculFragment();
                case 1 : return new EquationsResultatFragment();
                case 2 : return new EquationsInfosFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return int_items;

        }

        /**
         * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
         */

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return "Calcul";
                case 1 :
                    return "Résultats";
                case 2 :
                    return "Infos";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You're trying to access results (TextView) but EquationsResultatFragment's view is not created yet.

Comment: So, when sould I call the `getResultat(...)` method ?

Comment: I think it's not a good approach to do things this way, For more consistency use the parent activity as an interface to pass data between fragments.

Comment: I edited my post with my parent activity code. Because they are tabs, I think my fragments are already created when I arrive in EquationsCalculFragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you cannot directly communicate between different fragments. You need to go through your container activity for it.

Declare a listener interface through which your fragment will communicate with your container activity. Attach that listener to your `EquationsCalculFragment`. Your container activity should implement that listener.
Now when you `EquationsCalculFragment` wants  to communicate with `EquationsResultatFragment` you notify your container activity using that listener. In the container activity, when you get the listener callback, grab your `EquationsResultatFragment` fragment instance using `findFragmentById(int id)` or `findFragmentByTag(String tag)` and check if it is already added to your container activity. If it is, then call any public method of `EquationsResultatFragment` fragment, using that grabbed `EquationsResultatFragment` fragment instance.

Check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for more details and sample code.

Comment: I edited my post with my parent activity code. Because they are tabs, I think my fragments are already created when I arrive in EquationsCalculFragment (the first tab). Do you think I already need to set a listener interface ?

Comment: I guess you need to first understand the difference between Activity and  a Fragment. TabFragment.java is a fragment not an Activity.  " Do you think I already need to set a listener interface ? " - Yes.

Comment: I set up a listener in TabFragment, and now it works well, thank you. For other people who have this problem, take care to instantiate your "Fragment B" before use.

Answer (score 0):

`EquationsResultat`'s `getResultat` is called when you click on the `EquationsCalculFragment`'s button, and should set `EquationsResultat`'s `TextView` (`results`) text. Problem is, `results` is set on `EquationsResultat`'s `onCreateView`, and it seems this method has no been called yet, and therefore `results` is still null.

Post your activitie's code, it will be easier to help you knowing when you are attaching the fragments, etc.

Comment: I edited my post with my parent activity code. Because they are tabs, I think my fragments are already created when I arrive in EquationsCalculFragment (the first tab).

Answer (score -1):

Try this!!

```
public void getResultat(float a, float b) {
     results.setText(((a * a) + (2 * a * b) + (b * b))+"");
}
```